# BASH: Monitor/maintain a server

Tags: python, django, bash, port

I have a Django AWS server that I need to keep running over the weekend for it to be graded. I typically start it from an SSH using PuTTY with:

`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`


I was originally thinking of making a bash script to do the task of **starting the server, monitoring it, and restarting it** when needed using the but was told it wasn't going to work. Why?


**1)** Start the server using `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 &` to send it to the background

**2)** After `<some integer length 'x'>` minutes of sleeping, check if the server isn't up using `ss -tulw` and grep the result for the port the server should be running on.

**3)** Based on the result from step **(2)**, we either need to sleep for `'x'` minutes again, or restart the server (and possibly fully-stop anything left running beforehand). 

Originally, I thought it was a pretty decent idea, as we can't always be monitoring the server.

**EDIT:** Checked that `ss -tulw | grep 8000` correctly grabs the server while running server: 
[image]

Comment: Your question seems to be, *"why did my partner look at me in disbelief?"* - only your partner would be able to answer that. Did you ask them?

Comment: @kaya3 Him saying it wouldn't work and his expression when I explained it made me think I'm leaving out some critical piece of information. Since I'm not an expert at scripting with bash I thought that he was probably correct. He's currently unavailable.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I understand that this is more or less not how it's SUPPOSED to be used. Security issues aside (there's nothing there and it's backed up), we were specifically told to use Django as a starting point.

Comment: So just use Apache+mod_wsgi to run it properly, then you won’t have to have a shell script at all

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Thank you, I'm looking into this as we speak. However, for the sake of my concience, is there an error with the process I outlined?

Comment: There’s nothing wrong per sé except that you also need to use nohup to make sure the script and it’s children aren’t killed when you log out.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand you correctly, this is a non-production Django app.  You could run a test server using Django's development server like `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` as you did.

Thinks like monit (https://mmonit.com/monit/) or supervisord (http://supervisord.org/) are meant to do what you described - monitoring a process and restart it if necessary, but you could also just use a cron job that runs perhaps every minute.  In the cron job, you:

1. Check whether your process is still running and or still listening on port 8000.
2. Abort if already running.
3. Restart if stopped or not listening to port 8000.

Comment: Still, there is a huge difference between monit and supervisord! Monit is a monitoring solution that "executes", while supervisor "runs" a application. Or: Every monit exec has a timeout (defaults to 30s) while any supervisord application keeps running until exited.